# ObservableObject has a different instantiation in my class

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an ObservableObject that stores the current country the user is wanting information on and I want this to be shared across all views and classes. I properly declared it in the scene delegate so there is no issue with that.

```
import Foundation

class GlobalData: ObservableObject {

    @Published var whichCountry: String = "italy"
}
```

This is my main view of where I call an environment object to get whichCountry. When the users click the button it will open ListOfCountriesView() and pass that EnvironemtnObject through it to update the new country the users want.

```
import SwiftUI

struct InDepthView: View {
    @State var showList = false
    @EnvironmentObject var globalData: GlobalData
    @ObservedObject var data = getDepthData(globalData: GlobalData())

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Button(action: { self.showList.toggle() }) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(self.data.globalDatam.whichCountry.uppercased())")
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showList) {
                ListOfCountriesView().environmentObject(GlobalData())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListOfCountriesView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var globalData: GlobalData

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 15) {
                Text("List of Countries")
                    .padding(.top, 25)

                    Button(action: {
                        self.globalData.whichCountry = "usa"
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(self.globalData.whichCountry)")
                                .font(.system(size: 25))
                            Divider()
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListOfCountriesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListOfCountriesView().environmentObject(GlobalData())
    }
}
```

When the user changes the country I want this class which is inside my InDepthView.swift file to be updated with the new string. But for some reason, it is still displaying "italy" when it should have changed to "usa" based on what happened in ListOfCountriesView(). So I know that there is two instantiations of GlobalData but I'm not sure how to fix this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been spending the past two days trying to fix this issue!

```
class getDepthData: ObservableObject {

    @Published var data : Specific!
    @Published var countries : HistoricalSpecific!
    var globalDatam: GlobalData

    init(globalData: GlobalData) {
        globalDatam = globalData
        print(globalDatam.whichCountry + " init()")
        updateData()
    }

    func updateData() {

        let url = "https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries/" // specific country    
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default

        session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url+"\(self.globalDatam.whichCountry)")!) { (data, _, err) in

            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }

            let json = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Specific.self, from: data!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.data = json
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

///////
I added this to the code like you  mentioned. but recieving an error

```
import SwiftUI

struct InDepthView: View {
    @State var showList = false
    @State var pickerSelectedItem = 1
    @EnvironmentObject var globalData: GlobalData
    @ObservedObject var data: getDepthData

    init() {
        self.data = getDepthData(globalData: self.globalData)
    }
```

ERRROR : self' used before all stored properties are initialized

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a second GlobalData instance when you call

```
   @ObservedObject var data = getDepthData(globalData: GlobalData())
```

Edit: Removed example that was passing the environment object in as an argument. That doesn't work and it crashes.

You will need to refactor a bit to either structure your app a bit differently altogether, or you could remove the environment object, and instead initialise GlobalData() in your first view and then just pass it into each subsequent view as an @ObservedObject, rather than as @EnvironmentObject via scene delegate.

The following is pseudocode but I hope clarifies what I mean:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var globalData = GlobalData()
    var body: some View {
        ...
        NavigationLink("Linky link", destination: SecondView(globalData: globalData, data: getDepthData(globalData: globalData))
    }
    }

struct SecondView: View {
    @ObservedObject var globalData: GlobalData
    @ObservedObject var data: getDepthData
    init(globalData: GlobalData, data: getDepthData) {
        self.globalData = globalData
        self.data = getDepthData
    }
        ...
}
```

Comment: with the init() are you referring to the one in getDepthData class or  IndepthView class

Comment: Edited my answer. My apologies, it was bad. You can't pass in an Environment variable into another object like that. You will need to pass the object manually between your views and classes.

Comment: Ok  thanks make some more sense. But how does the getDepthData class handle this inside its class?

Comment: Should be the same as how you were using it before with the environment object. I'm not able to figure out what your code is trying to do and it doesn't build for me due to the undefined objects.